# The 'slow' animation speed is not working

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an animation, but it always runs fast, despite having 'slow', I have tried integers too, but they still have no affect. I tested similar animation on other elements, and they react to slow.

THE ANIMATION

```
$('#customers_delete_link').click(function(){ 
    $('#customers_delete_link_anim').animate(
        {'width': '200px'},'slow', function() {
            $('#customers_delete_popup').fadeOut();
            hide_check_toolbar();
        }
    );
});
```

// HTML

```
        <div id="customers_delete_link_cont">
            <div id="customers_delete_link">Delete Prospects</div>
            <div id="customers_delete_link_anim"></div>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{duration: 5000}` instead of `'slow'`:

```
$('#customers_delete_link').click(function(){ 
   $('#customers_delete_link_anim').animate(
        {width: '200px'},{duration: 5000}, function() {
            $('#customers_delete_popup').fadeOut();
            hide_check_toolbar();
        }
    );
});`
```

Change the duration value to change speed

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the animation duration then you can decide the animation duration exactly rather than just saying slow.

**check the below snippet:**

```js
var dur;

function animate(){
    $('.progress').stop();
    $('.progress').animate({width: '100%'},
    {
     duration: dur,
      easing: 'linear',
     queue: false,
      done: function(){
       $(this).css({width: '0%'});
      }
    })
};

$('.slow').click(function(){
    dur = 5 * 1000;
    animate();
});

$('.fast').click(function(){
   dur = 0.5 * 1000;
   animate();
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 0%;
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="fast">fast</button>
<button class="slow">slow</button>

<div class="progress"></div>
```